# Minibike/ coleman ct100u

Tags: starting, coleman, mini-bike

I’ve got a coleman Ct100u minibike that has spark but will not start. New carburetor (old one broke in a crash). I’ve pull started it about 30 times but then I gave up. I’ve got fuel, and all the essentials but I just cannot get it to even attempt to start. pull start is easy, no restriction when I pull it. It sat for about 6 months previous to this issue.

Comment: After a few pulls, when you remove the spark plugs and inspect them, are they wet?  If so, check for spark. If not wet you have a fuel related issue (generally something stuck in the carburetor). Old fuel turns to varnish and plugs up key passages in the carburetor.

Comment: were you able to resolve this? I have the same exact issue. changed out fuel and oil. I think I want to replace the spark plug next.

Answer (score 0):

Starting takes:

1. Fuel
2. Air
3. Spark
4. Compression

And these in the right order and proportions.  You said:

> pull start is easy, no restriction when I pull it

That doesn't sound right.  You should feel some resistance when the engine is on the compression stroke.  I'd start checking there.  Try removing the spark plug and pulling the starter and see if it's moving air in and out as expected.